# http4s route matching for GET requests with params on root host

Tags: scala, routes, get, http4s, partial-functions

I have simple rout-mapping function which using `http4s`:

```
import cats.syntax.all._
import org.http4s._
import org.http4s.circe._

def routeMapper: PartialFunction[Request[F], F[Response[F]]] = {
  case r @ POST -> Root => create
  case r @ PUT -> Root / id => update(id)
  case GET -> Root :? Published(published) => searchByPublishedDate(published)
  case GET -> Root                   =>
    println("show all called")
    showAll
  case GET -> Root / id              => searchById(id)
  case DELETE -> Root      => deleteAll
  case DELETE -> Root / id => delete(id)
}

object Published extends QueryParamDecoderMatcher[String]("published")

// I use this rout mapper to create HttpRoutes for HttpServer
def routes: HttpRoutes[F] = HttpRoutes.of[F](routeMapper)
```

For some reason when I try to pass **GET** request with some param which is not `published` to my server, I see result of `showAll` method.

For example, if I send get request on `http://{host}:{port}/?foo=somevalue`

I expect to see something like `org.http4s.dsl.impl.Status.BadRequest` or `org.http4s.dsl.impl.Status.NotFound` in `Response` but I see that it matches `case GET -> Root` actually.

Why it happens and how I can avoid this matching?

As I got partial functions are used for such cases when we want to define function only for some specified arguments (or types) but not for all possible inputs.

Comment: I am not familiar with http4s, but it seems like you explicitly asked for it. It fall into the `case GET -> Root` path. Isn't it? Why would you expect it not to fall into that case? Because of the extra parameter?

Comment: You'll find the same behaviour in akka routes.

Comment: @TomerShetah I thought that defining some cases with parameters for example: `case GET -> Root :? Published(published)` will prevent situation with some unexpected parameter but it does not help. Now it is (`:? SomeParamWrapper(value)`) only needed for unapply parameter and get some value. Maybe it should be so, I'm just trying to clarify it.

Comment: It will catch all requests with the `published` parameter. Any get that dose not have it, will fall into the default. Actually I can't find how to get all query parameters, which is pretty easy with akka. If you can do that, you should check if the map is empty or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments, case `case GET -> Root =>` will match all requests for the root path regardless of extra parameters.

To make this check stricter you could just reject that case if there's any parameter:

```
case request @ GET -> Root if request.params.isEmpty =>
```

it will match only if params map is empty.